# Lua C Function is not called when run in Android

Tags: android, c++, lua

I have this situation. Please look at the codes below before I move on to my issue (which i could not describe properly in the title)

My lua initializing codes:

```
luaState = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(luaState);
RegisterFunctions(luaState);
```

My lua loading codes:

```
try {
        luaL_dofile(luaState, scriptPath.c_str());
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout << "LUA ERROR: Could not load file " << std::endl;

    }
    loaded_.push_back(filename);
```

The part where I defined my C Functions:

```
int testFunction(lua_State* L)
{
    std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
void RegisterFunctions(lua_State* L)
{
    lua_register(L, "testFunction", testFunction);

}
```

My Lua script:

```
test = {};

function test:testCallback(me)
    testFunction();
end
```

These codes are able to build and run correctly in Android. However, when testFunction() is called, it did not enter the C Function which I defined. Everything works except this. I have also tested it on IOS and on IOS, it enters the testFunction as well. The issue only happens with Android and I am at a loss. Would appreciate if anyone has any advice.

Comment: What is the value of `testFunction`? Maybe try printing it before calling the function. An unrelated thing - the colon syntax (`function test:testCallback(me)`) will create a function that takes 2 arguments - `self` and `me`. So you don't need `me` if you're looking for an equivalent of `this`.

Comment: I don't think `luaL_dofile` ever throws an exception, because it uses `lua_pcall`, a protected call. If you really want to catch Lua errors this way, you need to use `lua_call` function and make sure Lua is compiled in C++ mode with exceptions.

Comment: testFunction is not been called at all. i know it has nothing to do with luaL_dofile as when my lua_pcall managed to execute without any error.

Comment: You're not giving us much to work with here - just saying it doesn't work doesn't help. How do you know the function is not getting called? Not seeing the `cout`'ed text does not necessarily mean Lua is not calling it/trying to call it. Have you tried attaching a debugger with a breakpoint on the function call? Any Lua debuggers you've tried? Does the execution of the script stop at that point or does it appear to skip over the function and continue (maybe Lua ran into an error)?

Comment: try crashing your program intentionally in `testFunction()` to see if it gets called.